# Questions about Advertising

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I recently viewed an advertisement, and I wanted to ask someone knowledgeable in marketing a question about it. Is there a site appropriate for that on Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an [Area51 proposal for a Marketing site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75798/marketing), but it's still  in the "definition" phase. You could help it reach beta by voting and adding example questions to it.

Comment: Thanks! That means my question is currently not appropriate on stack exchange then?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, unless you can think about another SE site to ask it (I could not).

Answer (score 2):

If your question is about graphical aspects, such as composition, colours, font choice, etc., it could be appropriate for [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).